# Recursive Oracle query to get ultimate target but not intermediate paths

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion, recursive-query

I'm trying to write a query that seems pretty basic in the world of `connect by` queries. But somehow I'm missing one important piece. I want to know for each "source" id what the ultimate "target" id is. For example, I have this source data:

```
src trg
1   2
2   3
3   4
7   8
```

My [current incarnation (SQL Fiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/30f4a/3/0) of the query returns the desired values:

```
select src, connect_by_root trg ult_trg
from t 
connect by nocycle prior src = trg
order by ult_trg, src;
```

The problem is that it *also* returns undesired values. My desired output is this:

```
1, 4
2, 4
3, 4
7, 8
```

What is the missing idea I need to limit my result set to the desired rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
  connect_by_root src as src,
  trg ult_trg
from t 
where 
  connect_by_isleaf = 1
  connect by nocycle src = prior trg
order by ult_trg, src
```

Comment: I accepted @pm-77-1 since his was both first and correct. But this idea is correct and very interesting. It's sort of backwards (PRIOR trg instead of PRIOR src) from how I did it. There is no need for the nested query. Your answer will be cleaner with just `WHERE CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1` in the main query.

Answer (score 1):

```
select src, MAX(connect_by_root trg) ult_trg
from t 
connect by nocycle prior src = trg
GROUP BY src
order by ult_trg, src;
```

Modified [**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/30f4a/13)

Comment: This works for Number, but in real, it doesn't fetch the ultimate path? And will not work for texts!

Comment: Sorry, I moved my accepted answer to @MaheswaranRavisankar. Your answer was fine for the sample data. But in the more general case my IDs do not necessarily increase. So `MAX()` doesn't return the desired value in all cases.